# VB.NET - TextBox1.text on form run will focus on the text I want to unfocus

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Just a quick question my textbox1.text seems to get focus when I run the APP.

how do I cancel any focus to any textbox?

I just don't want to select it or anything when I work with it only when the user select or uses it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `TabStop` for the textbox to `False.`